# VHDL pass range to procedure

Tags: vhdl

I'm writing my own package to deal with generic matrix-like objects due to unavailability of VHDL-2008 (I'm only concerned with compilation and simulation for the time being).
My aim is getting a matrix M_out from a matrix M_in such that:

```
M_out(i downto 0, j downto 0) <= M_in(k+i downto k, l+j downto l);
```

using a subroutine of sort. For, let's say, semantic convenience and analogy with software programming languages my subroutine prototype should ideally look something like this:

```
type matrix is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
...
procedure slice_matrix(signal m_out: out matrix;
                       constant rows: natural range<>;
                       constant cols: natural range<>;
                       signal m_in: in matrix);
```

The compiler does however regard this as an error:

```
** Error: custom_types.vhd(9): near "<>": syntax error
** Error: custom_types.vhd(9): near "<>": syntax error
```

Is it possible to pass a range as an argument in some way or shall I surrender and pass 4 separate indexes to calculate it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unconstrained index range `natural range <>` is not a VHDL object of class signal, variable, constant, or file. Thus it can not be passed into a subprogram. I wouldn't implement a slice operations as a procedure, because it's a function like behavior.

An implementation for working with matrices and slices thereof is provided by the [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC). The implementation is provided in the [vectors package](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl).

```
function slm_slice(slm : T_SLM; RowIndex : natural; ColIndex : natural; Height : natural; Width : natural) return T_SLM is
  variable Result       : T_SLM(Height - 1 downto 0, Width - 1 downto 0)        := (others => (others => '0'));
begin
  for i in 0 to Height - 1 loop
    for j in 0 to Width - 1 loop
      Result(i, j)      := slm(RowIndex + i, ColIndex + j);
    end loop;
  end loop;
  return Result;
end function;
```

More specialized functions to slice off a [row](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl#L274-L283) or [column](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl#L285-L294) can be found in that file too. It also provides procedures to assign parts of a matrix.

This package works in simulation and synthesis.

Unfortunately, slicing multi dimensional arrays will not be part of [VHDL-2017](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/VHDL2017). I'll make sure it's discuss for VHDL-202x again.

Passing ranges into a subprogram will be allowed in VHDL-2017. The language change [LCS 2016-099](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/LCS2016_099) adds this capability.

Comment: Seeing that the compiler on the server at my university does not support VHDL-2008 yet I guess I won't get access to new features very soon, but it is nice to know. Passing integers it is then.